# What are these alien egg-like things on the back of rose leaves?

Tags: flowers, leaves, roses

A friend received roses, and on the back are these mysterious things. It's not everywhere, but it's behind the back of many of the leaves. Anyone know what they are?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

It is not a rose, but a fern. Fern usually have sori (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorus), which are used to disperse spores.

Ferns have no flowers, so no seeds.

Note the white flowers come from a different plant, which is also not a rose, but I cannot identify it.

Comment: The white flowers: Baby's breath ([Gypsophila paniculata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gypsophila_paniculata).